# Is it possible to draw a line between two objects placed based on location in ar.js

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js

I am using ar.js to show some object on camera, now I need to draw a line between two objects placed based on location. I used a frame for placing objects. Is there any possible solution??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Line](https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/components/line.html) Component?

You can create an entity, add a line component and pass in the points to the component:

```
<a-entity line="start: 0, 1, 0; end: 2 0 -5; color: red"
          line__2="start: -2, 4, 5; end: 0 4 -3; color: green"></a-entity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that but in that case there is no option to draw line between 2 location, I need to connect two places with a line. Is there any possible way

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by location? If you can get a position for a location that can be given to the line component.

Comment: Location means I am placing two objects based on two different latitude and longitude. For example I am placing one object at 10.093333 , 76.0033333 and another object on 10.0334449 ,76.0004444. I need to draw a line connecting these two objects. Is that possible?

Comment: Hmmm not sure how latitude longitude enters the picture. Don't have experience with ar.js. My first guess would be to convert those long/lats into a position relative to your scene.